# Building Android on One Machine and Emulating it on Another

Tags: android, build, android-emulator

I haven't been able to find anything on this. Apologies if this duplicates anything in existence.

I'm currently have a virtual version of Ubuntu 10.10 accessing a shared folder in my main OS (Arch Linux) to build Android. I can successfully build it and run the emulator from my virtual machine. (The make file updates my shell appropriately, correct?) When I go to my actual OS and try to run the same emulator, I get an error that states:

```
$ ./out/host/linux-x86/bin/emulator
emulator: ERROR: You did not specify a virtual device name, and the system directory could not be found
```

I have tried setting ANDROID_PRODUCT_OUT to the same value on my actual computer, but I still get the same error. Is this just a simple error, or should I just stick to running the emulator on my virtual machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a complete answer, but I was able to do what I wanted to by creating an Ubuntu partition on my computer and chrooting into it and forwarding the X display.

References for doing this:

- http://source.android.com/source/initializing.html
- https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Change_Root

After setting up my Ubuntu environment, I made the following script to chroot into it (this is nearly taken directly from the 2nd source):

```
xhost +

cd /mnt/ubuntu

mount           /dev/sda2 /mnt/ubuntu
mount -t proc   proc      proc/
mount -t sysfs  sys       sys/
mount -o bind   /dev      dev/
mount -t devpts pts       dev/pts/

mount -o bind   /mnt/data mnt/data/
mount -o bind   /home     home/

chroot /mnt/ubuntu /bin/sh -c "export DISPLAY=:0.0; /bin/bash -i"

umount {proc,sys,dev/pts,dev}
umount {mnt/data,home}
cd .. && umount ubuntu
```

Then go to your android root directory ($android), set up the environment and build it. Starting the emulator should then start it in the current X session.

```
cd $android
. build/envsetup.sh
lunch full-eng
make -j16
emulator
```